# How to handle 301 redirection loops?

Tags: 7

I'm working on **custom 301 redirect** module. I am getting a redirection loop if **source url** ==  `www.xyz.com/aboutus/*.php` and **destination url** == `www.xyz.com/aboutus/xyz.php`

or **source url** = `/abc/*` and **destination url** = `/abc/legal-disclaimer`

**How can one handle such type of redirections?**

How can I **validate source url with wildcard** while submitting **source url** and **target url** in form? Because during form submission, if I write

```
drupal_match_path($current_path_alias,$source_url)
```

This will not gonna work as `$current_path_alias` is not the **source url** that I have passed in form.

**Any way to break this redirection loops??**